# javascript, how to remove the <html><head><body> elements when using DOMparser with text/html

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom, domparser

The code

```
var txt = '<div id="hi">fe</div><div id="h2">fe</div><div id="hj">fe</div>'
var parser = new DOMParser();
var temp_node = parser.parseFromString(txt, "text/html").documentElement;
console.log(temp_node)
```

This code results in the full html document, this is including

```
<html><head></head><body>
<div id="hi">fe</div>
<div id="h2">fe</div>
<div id="hj">fe</div>
</body></html>
```

What if I want only the `<div id="hi">fe</div><div id="h2">fe</div><div id="hj">fe</div>` part? How can I do it?

And, if I want to append all nodes, is there a way to do it without a loop?

```
parentNode.appendChile(temp_node) // add the entire code
parentNode.appendChile(temp_node.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling) // add the parent <body> and the other layers inside
parentNode.appendChild(temp_node.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling.childNodes) // doesn't do the trick, it complains about not being a "node", I guess I'd need an "appendChilds" function that allows to add many nodes at once
```

*What I'd wish, if parentNode is `<div id="parent">`

```
<div id="parent">
 <div id="hi">fe</div>
 <div id="h2">fe</div>
 <div id="hj">fe</div>
</div>
```

But I get

```
<div id="parent">
 <body>
  <div id="hi">fe</div>
  <div id="h2">fe</div>
  <div id="hj">fe</div>
 </body>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `childNodes`

```
console.log(temp_node.childNodes[1].childNodes[0]);
```

or `querySelector`

```
console.log(temp_node.querySelector("#hi"));
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davcs86/m4thydjd/)

**Update**

or `innerHTML`

```
console.log(temp_node.querySelector("body").innerHTML);
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davcs86/m4thydjd/1/)

Comment: That works if I only have once child, but I do have many (question updated).

Comment: use `temp_node.querySelector("body").innerHTML`

Comment: Yes, but no since I need the DOM structure. It seems that with innerHTML it is lost (isn't it?)

Comment: then `temp_node.childNodes[1].childNodes` (without index)

Comment: Yes, that's it, and I am using createDocumentFragment to append all ChildNodes to the parent div

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.body` instead:

```js
parser.parseFromString(txt, "text/html").body
```

When you use the property `.documentElement` as you did in your code, it returns the following:

> Returns the Element that is a direct child of the document. For HTML
> documents, this is normally the *HTMLHtmlElement* object representing
> the document's `<html>` element.
>
> - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement)

Other properties exist on the [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document), `.body` is one of which. Using `.body` (instead of `querySelector()`) will give you fast and direct access to the `body` of your HTML content, which you can then use `.innerHTML` on to get its inner contents as a string:

See working example:

```js
const txt = '<div id="hi">fe</div><div id="h2">fe</div><div id="hj">fe</div>'
const parser = new DOMParser();
const temp_node = parser.parseFromString(txt, "text/html").body;
console.log(temp_node.innerHTML);
```